# How to re-oder a dataframe in pandas using a string in cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to re-order a dataframe in pandas by locating the cell which contains the string `negative`, delete this row and instead add a new column into the dataframe which distinguishes the rows before the cell which contains the string `negative` and call them `'POSITIVE'` whereas the rows which used to be after the string, call them `'NEGATIVE'`.

This is a minimal example of the dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 'negative', 4,5], 
'col2': [6,7,None, 8,9],
'col3':[10,11,None,12,13] }

data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This is what I have been trying to acheive:

```
arget = {'col1': [1, 2, 4, 5], 
'col2': [6,7, 8,9],
'col3':[10,11, 12,13],
'col4':['POSTIVE','POSTIVE','NEGATIVE', 'NEGATIVE' ] }
target = pd.DataFrame(data= target)
```

I have tried to split the dataframe, then remove the row and then add the new column and finally join them again. I was wondering if there is a better way in pandas to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare by `negative` for first `mask`, then add cumulative sum and compare for previous values to `mask1`, pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and last remove `negative` rows by invert mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = data['col1'].eq('negative')
mask1 = mask.cumsum().eq(0)

data['col4'] = np.where(mask1, 'POSTIVE','NEGATIVE')
data = data[~mask].copy()
print (data)
  col1  col2  col3      col4
0    1   6.0  10.0   POSTIVE
1    2   7.0  11.0   POSTIVE
3    4   8.0  12.0  NEGATIVE
4    5   9.0  13.0  NEGATIVE
```

Comment: Amazing, it worked very well. Can I ask why did you use `.eq(1)` in `mask1`. I'm not sure how `mask1` is working?

Comment: @Sam - I like `cumsum` for cumulative sum here, because if test `print (mask.cumsum())` it generate `0` until first `True`, here value with `negative`

Comment: @Sam - Also solution working if no value `nagative` correct, all values are POSITIVE